# Worldbuilding chat feeds?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

Inspired by [RPG.SE's RSS voting meta Q](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3041/4398), I'd like to suggest that we consider what RSS feeds we should put in our [main chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilding). I've found that site meta questions in the chat proper and mainsite questions in the ticker feed are a good idea for most SE site chats, but if there are blogs or news feeds we'd find appropriate to our topic, those should get suggested too!

Comment: Should we have a minimum upvote requirement on feeds, like on RPG.SE?

Comment: @shatterspike1 That process evolved organically over time, and I think ours should too. So far there haven't been *any* non-site feeds suggested.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with meta as posted chat messages and main site as ticker feeds. Works well for RPG.SE

Comment: Meta posts in chat works well in Programming Puzzles and Code Golf too. I think promoting meta is important.